# How to find out what an Image is about

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, graph-algorithm

Is there a way to understand what an image is about? I mean, if I scann a picture, how can I tell that the picture is about a spesific object? I am thinking that if I have some shape in mind, say the shape - pattern of a spesific object that meets its requirements against the object I am searhcing for, then it must be what I am looking for. Anyway I am thinking of an algorithm to scann a picture database and figure out the pictures I am actually looking for,Is there a known way to accomplish such operation?.

Comment: Can you imagine how much a reliable solution to this problem is worth?

Comment: I think, possibilities truly must be a key for this task. But isn't there a way to increase the possibilities by pattern matching and increase the worthiness of such algorithm ?

Comment: I mean if your looking for a picture that represents a knife then a knife has a specific shape in different angles. I know that  you mean that there must be other shapes that really match the same object but in different angles as well, so how can you tell the difference.  But also color must be a factor here. Anyway Is there some software out there that does that?

Comment: This is something they do in [face detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_detection), but it is not 100% reliable.

Comment: This is a good start "Many algorithms implement the face-detection task as a binary pattern-classification task. That is, the content of a given part of an image is transformed into features, after which a classifier trained on example faces decides whether that particular region of the image is a face, or not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly...

This is a very daunting task even for full-fledged corporations like Google, though they are attempting to create something along these lines.

Take a look at Google Goggles for Android if you'd like to see how this sort of system behaves. You'll also notice that it requires very specific circumstances to be even slightly reliable, but the base technology is there.

Comment: very interesting that is what I was thinking, so how is this possible? Is it done by matching the pixels? what algorithm is used ?

Comment: Their code is proprietary, but methods for recognition of basic shapes are available through libraries such as OpenCV. If you'd like to learn more about image recognition I'd start by looking into this (or a similar) library.

Comment: Do you think that it is also about "pattern-classification task" ?

Comment: I think this is a bit higher-level than a simple classification task. Your question above is sort of like asking whether a car is made out of simple machines, and while the answer *is* yes, it isn't the entire answer.

Comment: Well what I was simply asking is done by google anyway, thank you